# How to configure a vhost for zendframework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I would like to configure a vhost to zf, but I have no idea how to do it, please if you could help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The process of creating a virtual host, depends on the **version of APACHE**, but overall remains the same.

**APACHE** (Scroll Down for **APACHE2**)

If your using regular apache, such as apache on the MAMP stack or Centos, You do the following.

Edit your httpd.conf file, in your apache conf directory, Add this to the end of the file.
(if using mamp, its in applications/mamp/conf/apache otherwise it should be in /etc/apache/conf)

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName quickstart.local
     DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/quickstart/public
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     <Directory /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/quickstart/public>
          DirectoryIndex index.php
          AllowOverride All
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After this, restart apache,

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache restart
```

or restart via your xamp stack client if it exists.

You now need to let your browser be aware of the domain name "quickstart.local" in this case.

Go into your hosts file.

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

add the following line.

```
127.0.0.1       quickstart.local
```

exit

**All done.**

---

**If your using APACHE2,** you do the same thing, but instead of editing the httpd.conf file.
Go into your /etc/apache2.conf

make sure

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
```

Is uncommented.

Now go into sites-available.

Create a new file name it the domain name, in this case "quickstart.local"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName quickstart.local
ServerAlias quickstart.local
DocumentRoot /var/www/quickstart/public #or whatever the path is.
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
 <Directory /var/www/quickstart/public>
      DirectoryIndex index.php
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

save

Now go into your sites-enabled folder.

do the following

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/quickhost.local .
```

Now go edit the Hosts file like discussed above (If a made up domain name).
**You should be good.**

If if this is not working , it may be that you dont have your directory enabled for .htaccess.

For Zend to work, you need to make sure that the directory is set to

"AllowOveride ALL"

```
<Directory <Path to whatever>>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

This allows the Zend routing system to work. This is set to off by default sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

I usually had these  in my apache's config in `/etc/apache/sites-enabled/000-default`
in this case i am using ubuntu +apache 2 :

```
NameVirtualHost zf.local:80
<VirtualHost zf.local:80>
DocumentRoot "/home/devlor/Sites/zf/public"
ServerName symfony.local
  SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
    <Directory "/home/devlor/Sites/zf/public">
      Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

@ tawfekov:

Won't work if `/home/devlor` isn't in Apache's trusted dir list:

```
<Directory /home>
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from none
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: i had used it a zillion times , if it won't , please provide me with the error message and i will make sure to fix

Comment: and it must work in windows too , i did a screencast about setup ZF + WAMP two years ago http://www.zendcasts.com/getting-started-with-zend-and-wamp-server/2009/06/

Comment: +1 I didn't say your code was wrong, but merely incomplete. Most probably you have `/home` setup in httpd.conf as I noted above - normally, you should make sure VHOST dir is within Apache's allowed Directories' scope, in order to avoid 403 Forbidden errors. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName overstock.local
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\overstock"
 <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\overstock">
    AllowOverride All
   </Directory>

 </VirtualHost>
```

Then change htaccess to

```
   Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /overstock/

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```